# LocalStorage error and idea

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
// store item
localStorage.setItem("blog_key", "value I am storing");

// retrieve item
var data = localStorage.getItem("blog_key");
```

I'm trying to make it list of array for the post, so when somenone click post, it will serve as blog post

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is not working properly?

Comment: am trying to make it like db but it is overwritten the prev stored data

Comment: but when i try localStorage.setItem(Date.now(), "value I am storing"); it won't overwrite but it will not display

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question or not but I guess you want to do something like this:

```
// retrieve the local storage value or "[]" and then parse it
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blog_key") || "[]");

// add new item to the array - might want to make sure that the array wont grow too big
data.push("something new"); 

// store item as string
localStorage.setItem("blog_key", JSON.stringify(data));
```

I might be wrong though, but that's what I got from your question.

Comment: okay i tried the all in array how will you now select cause this is my new error. when i post localStorage.getItem("blog_key") i will get
"["something new","sehis man new"]" but if i post localStorage.getItem("blog_key")[0] i will get
"["

Comment: Have done it, now i will i selects one for the local storage